# Write a method to compute the following series

Tags: java, methods

I am in need of help with a school assignment. I'm really stuck and have tried searching in multiple places online to no avail.

Well, here is the question.

- (Sum series) Write a method
- `public static double m(int i)`
- to compute the following series:

Write a test program that displays the following table:

```
i                                                    m(i)
__________________________________
1                                                   0.5000
2                                                   1.1667
...
19                                                  16.4023
20                                                  17.3546
```

I have the method done, but I don't know how to print the table. I asked my teacher, and apparently, the method itself isn't supposed to print the table, which is what has gotten me stuck in this assignment. I have only managed to print the labels at the top of the table.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Assignment18 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        double value = 0;
        int i;
        System.out.println("i" + "\t\t" + "m(i)");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
    }

    public static double m(int i) {
        double sum = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 21; i++)
            sum += (double) i / (i + 1); 
        System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + sum + "\n");
        return sum; 
    }
}
```

Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to proceed to print the table correctly? Thank you. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what series? show the summation formula

Comment: You don't seem to be calling the `m` method in `main`

Answer (score 1):

A function like `m(i)` should return the value you are asked to calculate. If the function prints out the value, this is known as a side-effect.

You would then have a different part of your code print the table, by asking `m()` for the values.

```
System.out.println("i" + "\t\t" + "m(i)");
System.out.println("-------------------");

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    System.out.println(""+ i + "\t\t" + m(i) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this it'sfunctionally

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        double value = 0;
        int i;
        System.out.println("i" + "\t\t" + "m(i)");
        System.out.println("-------------------"); 
        m(7);
    }

    public static void m(int i) {
        double sum = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 21; i++){
            sum += (double) i / (i + 1); 
        System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + sum + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Dog, all you need is some braces:

```
public static double m(int i) 
{
    double sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        sum += (double) i / (i + 1); 
        System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + sum + "\n");
    }
    return sum; 
}
```

Comment: Dog, the problem is that "the method itself isn't supposed to print the table".

Comment: Yea Dog! ;)  I'm assuming the teacher is purposely being somewhat vague in order to give this guy a hint without giving him the full answer. Are there explicit conditions that you can't print AND calculate the answer in one method?